# Convert Access database to SQLite

Tags: sqlite, ms-access, delphi, firemonkey

I found a solution to transfer the database to SQLite Access in the sample `C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\Samples\Object Pascal\Database\Fire DAC\Samples\Comp Layer\TFD Batch Move\Migrate` but when running the application with the my Access database is corrupted by a few tables with field names as column, please just help me fix 
[image: bug when running example]
[image: Errors due to the field name named column]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: `Column` is a keyword in Sql, which is why your column called Column is causing a problem.  In Sql, where you want to use Column as a name rather than the keyword, surround it by square brackets.

Comment: Dig into the code of that sample application. You will see it creating a field(column) named Column. Either extend the code in their to rename the target field or try [escaping the column names](sqlite escaping column names)